# How to check for GPU on CentOS Linux

Tags: c, linux, gpu, x86-64, gpgpu

It is suggested that on Linux, GPU be found with the command `lspci | grep VGA`. It works fine on Ubuntu but when I try to use the same on CentOS, it says lspci command is not found. How can I check for the GPU card on CentOS. And note that I'm not the administrator of the machine and I only use it remotely from command line. I intend to use the GPU as a GPGPU on that machine, but first I need to check if it even has one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried to launch `/sbin/lspci` or `/usr/sbin/lspci` ?

Answer (score 22):

This assumes you have proprietary drivers installed, but issue the following command...

```
nvidia-smi
```

The output should look similar to this:

```
Mon Dec 23 10:50:28 2013       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 331.20     Driver Version: 331.20         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 660     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 10%   38C  N/A     N/A /  N/A |     97MiB /  2047MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This gives the more specific information that I was looking for.

Comment: yes @hihell -- `watch -n 1 nvidia-smi` will refresh it every second.

Answer (score 8):

Try `lshw` or `lspci`. They have to be installed if you don't have already.

Install lshw

```
sudo yum install lshw //CentOS
sudo apt-get install lshw // Ubuntu
```

Then run this

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

The output would look like this

```
 *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:95 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:faf00000-faf7ffff
```

Similarly, you can try `lspci`

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

The output would look like this

```
0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 2):

lspci should be in the package pciutils.

you could do this with dmidecode but as your not an admin you probably cant do this nor installing the pciutils package.

IF there is a Xorg on this system then it should be easy:

```
grep Graphics /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use CUDA, it has a function to enumerate CUDA-capable devices on the system. Why not use that?