# How to compile FFMpeg with older NVEnc?

Tags: ffmpeg, google-kubernetes-engine, nvenc

I get this error when running FFMpeg with NVEnc.

```
[h264_nvenc @ 0x2a27d00] Driver does not support the required nvenc API version. Required: 9.1 Found: 9.0
[h264_nvenc @ 0x2a27d00] The minimum required Nvidia driver for nvenc is 435.21 or newer
```

I can't upgrade the driver to latest version because I'm limited by what's supported in GKE.

Comment: [Which Nvidia driver version are you using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125714/how-to-get-the-nvidia-driver-version-from-the-command-line)?

Answer (score 6):

Resolved.  I was compiling ffmpeg with the latest code in https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git 
Switching to the sdk/9.0 branch worked for the nvidia driver on GKE.

Comment: Thank you! Quick setup with dabei's tip: `git clone --branch sdk/9.0 https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git`

Answer (score 0):

Which drivers are supported largely depends on the node OS (COS or Ubuntu) and the GKE version the node is running. When you add a GPU node to your cluster, GKE provisions a DaemonSet that automatically installs the drivers for you. A list of supported NVIDIA driver versions per GKE version can be found in the document [1] that Google has at present.

The Nvidia drivers on your cluster get updated when the node itself gets an update to the newer version of GKE. You can follow the newest feature release of GKE in the document [2].

Now, as we do not have the required NVENC driver version, an alternative approach might be to pull required older version of FFmpeg.

[1]--https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gpus#installing_drivers

[2]--https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes